# Formulating a problem involving sets with ILP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

Consider set $\mathcal{G} = \{G_1, \ldots, G_K\}$. We are given $\mathcal{A}_i \subset \mathcal{G}$, $i \in 
\mathcal{N}= \{1,\ldots, N\}$ and for each $\mathcal{A}_i$, there is a corresponding cost denoted by $C_i$. We want to choose $\mathcal{A}_j$, $j \in \mathcal{J} \subset \mathcal{N}$ with minimum cost such that union of $\mathcal{A}_j$, $j \in \mathcal{J}$ is the set $\mathcal{G}$. Therefore, the problem is to $\min_{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_N} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{N}}\alpha_i C_i$ subject to $\cup_{i \in \mathcal{N}, \alpha_i=1} \mathcal{A}_i = \mathcal{G}$, $\alpha_i \in \{0,1\}$ for $i \in \mathcal{N}$.

Is it possible to write this problem as a standard ILP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me recapitulate (so that I understand this):

- You have a base set $G$ with $K$ elements.
- Then you have $N$ subsets $A^{(i)}$ of $G$, each comes with cost $C_i$.
- You want to cover $G$ with a selection of $A^{(i)}$ such that the cost is minimal.

We can model the selection of subsets via the vector of unknowns
$x \in \{ 0, 1 \}^N$.
For each set $A^{(i)}$ we have a vector $y^{(i)} \in \{ 0, 1 \}^K$ which is kind of its index function regarding $G$:
$$
y_j^{(i)} =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } A^{(i)}_j \in G \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
To cover $G$ a feasible selection $x$ of subsets $A^{(i)}$ must have at least one of each element of $G$ and thus fulfill the constraint
$$
1_K \le \sum_i x_i y^{(i)} = Y x
$$
where $1_K = (1, \dotsc, 1)^\top \in \{0,1\}^K$ and 
$Y = (y^{(1)}, \dotsc, y^{(N)}) \in \{0,1\}^{K \times N}$.

So we got the ILP:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\min & c^\top x \\
\text{w.r.t.} & Y x \ge 1_K \\
& x \in \{ 0, 1 \}^N
\end{array}
$$
where $c$ is the cost vector with components $C_i$.